# Typesript: how to get indexed object from tuple list of props

Tags: typescript

Input:

```
type Props = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Output derived from `Props` type:

```
type Obj = {
 a: string,
 b: string,
 c: string
}
```

Just can not figure out, but pretty sure it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a type query to get a union of the string literals in `Props` (`Props[number]`) and use `Record` to create the type with the specified props as strings.

```
type Obj = Record<Props[number], string>
```